# Turning WET jQuery into DRY

Tags: jquery

I have set up a 'media input box' to select images using the WordPress media selector and I am using jQuery to grab data from a WordPress post object to insert into an HTML preview field. This is working nicely for one 'media box', but now I want to expand this to two more boxes.

I could duplicate the jQuery code three times changing only one line ( containing the `parent` var) for each media box, but this is extremely WET. I am struggling to change my jQuery to account for the individual media box being used...

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

    function add_image(obj) 
    {
        var parent=jQuery(obj).parent().parent('div.image_a');
        var inputField = jQuery(parent).find("input.meta_image_url");           
        var fileFrame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({ multiple: false });     

        fileFrame.on('select', function() 
        {
            var wp_post = fileFrame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();      

            inputField.val(wp_post.url);                
            jQuery(parent)
                .find("div.image_preview")
                .html('<img src="'+wp_post.url+'" height="50" width="100" />');
        });

        fileFrame.open();
    };

</script>
```

and the HMTL

```
// First media box
<div class="image_a">
    <div class="image_url">
        <span>
            <label>Image A URL</label>
        </span>
        <input type="text"
            class="meta_image_url"
            name="image_b"
            value="<?php esc_html_e( $img_a_url ); ?>"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="image_preview">
        <img src="<?php esc_html_e( $img_a_url ); ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="image_buttons">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Choose File" onclick="add_image(this)" /><br />
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="remove_field(this)" />
    </div>
</div>  


//Second media box
<div class="image_b">
    <div class="image_url">
        <span>
            <label>Image B URL</label>
        </span>
        <input type="text"
            class="meta_image_url"
            name="image_a"
            value="<?php esc_html_e( $img_b_url ); ?>"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="image_preview">
        <img src="<?php esc_html_e( $img_b_url ); ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="image_buttons">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Choose File" onclick="add_image(this)" /><br />
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="remove_field(this)" />
    </div>
</div>  

//Third media box
<div class="image_c">
    <div class="image_url">
         ...
```

I don't mind changing the HTML to accommodate changes. Feel free to think up a more fitting title.

Comment: What do you mean by wet and dry?

Comment: Writing Everything Twice - or in this case, writing the jQuery block three times changing one line in each block. Don't Repeat Yourself, would be a slightly more complex jQuery block, but not duplicated three times...

Comment: Couldn't you just add a common class to all containers, e.g. `image` and change the `parent` line to `var parent=jQuery(obj).parent().parent('div.image');` or `var parent=jQuery(obj).parents('div.image');`. I would then personally change the current classes (`image_a`, `image_b`, `image_c`) to id's instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always add a second parameter to the add_image function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

function add_image(obj, parentSelector)
{
    var parent=jQuery(obj).parent().parent(parentSelector);
    var inputField = jQuery(parent).find("input.meta_image_url");           
    var fileFrame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({ multiple: false });     

    fileFrame.on('select', function() 
    {
        var wp_post = fileFrame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();      

        inputField.val(wp_post.url);                
        jQuery(parent)
            .find("div.image_preview")
            .html('<img src="'+wp_post.url+'" height="50" width="100" />');
    });

    fileFrame.open();
};

</script>
```

Then you can change your onclick attributes:

```
onclick="add_image(this, 'div.image_a')"
```

Comment: So clean. Can't believe I missed this.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a great candidate for a [jQuery plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/). With a plugin, you would have a nice, reusable component, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Here's some code that might get you started:

```
    $.fn.addImage = function() {
    // this -> context refers to selected elements.
    return this.each(function(){        // Returning this allows you to chain like other jQuery plugins
        var $this = $(this),
            $input = $this.find('input.meta_image_url')

        var fileFrame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({ multiple: false });     

        fileFrame.on('select', function(){
            var wp_post = fileFrame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();      

            $input.val(wp_post.url);                
            $this.find('div.image_preview')
                .html('<img src="' + wp_post.url + '" height="50" width="100" />');
        });

        fileFrame.open();
    });
};
```

Add a common class (say, `.add-image`) to your elements, and you'd call your plugin like this:

```
$('.add-image').addImage();
```

EDIT: I haven't used WordPress's file plugin stuff, so YMMV, but repeated code based around selecting and operating on a set of elements is generally a great place for a plugin.